# Invoking List<CompletableFuture> with timeout and collecting results

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, concurrency, completable-future

I am trying to stop many `Worker` instances with timeout of 2 seconds for each worker and I expect some of them to fail.
I want to achieve something like below and I know it's bad approach. I cant use CompletableFuture.allOf() because it stop on first fail. Also I never before used CompletableFutures.
I tried with Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3).invokeAll() with no success.

```
public interface Worker {

public String workerId();
public CompletableFuture<Worker> stop();
}

List<Worker> workers;

public stopAll() {

   workers.stream()
   .parallel()
   .map(worker -> 
       try {
           worker.stop().get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
       } catch(InterruptedException | java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException | TimeoutException e){
           log.error("Worker {} failed to stop", worker.workerId())
       }
}
```

My goal is:

1. stopAll() method takes approximately 2 seconds to finish
2. all workers that didn't stop in this time to be logged by Id

Does anyone got any suggestions ?
Thanks for any help.

Solution:

I was wrong about CompletableFuture.AllOf(). As I want to access workerId() after allOf completion I need to keep them in a map.

```
Map<CompletableFuture<Worker>, Worker> cfWorkerMap = workers.stream()
                    .parallel()
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .collect(toMap(
                            ExecEnvVerticle::stop,
                            Function.identity()
                    ))
try {
    CompletableFuture.allOf(
        cfWorkerMap.keySet().toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
            .get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (Exception e) {
    cfExecEnvMap.entrySet().parallelStream()
        .peek(entry -> {
            if (!entry.getKey().isDone()) {
                entry.getKey().completeExceptionally(new TimeoutException())
        .forEach(entry -> entry.getKey()
            .handle((execEnv, throwable) -> {
                if (Objects.nonNull(throwable)) {
                    log.error(entry.getValue().workerId())
                }
            return null;
            }
        ))
```

Comment: So your "stop" method starts up a CompletableFuture?  I'm confused as to what it actually does.

Comment: Yes. Does it matter what it does ? It does some work needed to stop which takes some time.

Answer (score 2):

There is no actual problem, as your proposition, “*I cant use CompletableFuture.allOf() because it stop on first fail*” is wrong. The future returned by `allOf` will be completed exceptionally if at least one of the input futures has been completed exceptionally, but it still will only be completed when all futures have been completed.
As can easily be demonstrated:

```
CompletableFuture<?> f1 = new CompletableFuture<>();
f1.completeExceptionally(new Throwable("fail immediately"));
CompletableFuture<?> f2
  = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(2)));
CompletableFuture<?> all = CompletableFuture.allOf(f1, f2);

long t0 = System.nanoTime();
try {
    all.join();
} finally {
    System.err.println("Completed: "+f1.isDone()+", "+f2.isDone());
    System.err.printf("%.2fs%n", (System.nanoTime()-t0)*1e-9);
}
```

```
Completed: true, true
2,00s
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.Throwable: fail immediately
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.biRelay(CompletableFuture.java:1284)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$BiRelay.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1270)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1632)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1618)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: fail immediately
    at Demo.main(Demo.java:16)
```

So you can use `allOf` to check the completion state of all jobs, even when some fail:

```
ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
Random r = ThreadLocalRandom.current();
CompletableFuture<?>[] workerJobs = IntStream.range(0, 20)
    .mapToObj(i -> {
      long time = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(r.nextInt(4000));
      boolean fail = r.nextBoolean();
      return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        LockSupport.parkNanos(time);
        if(fail) throw new RuntimeException();
      }, e);
    })
    .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new);
e.shutdown();

try {
  CompletableFuture.allOf(workerJobs).get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  System.out.println("All completed within 2 seconds or less without failures");
}
catch(InterruptedException ex) {
  throw new AssertionError(ex);
}
catch(ExecutionException ex) {
  System.out.println("All completed within 2 seconds or less, at least one failed");
}
catch(TimeoutException ex) {
  System.out.println("At least one did not complete within 2 seconds");
}
for(CompletableFuture<?> f: workerJobs) {
  System.out.println(f.isDone()? "completed"
    +(f.isCompletedExceptionally()? " exceptionally": ""): "not completed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have a great way to wait for a bunch of Completable Futures with a timeout (that I know of):

```
public class TryWaitForCF {

private void run() throws Exception {

    List<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>();
    for( int i=0; i<10; i++){
        workers.add(new Worker("Worker="+i));
    }

    List<CompletableFuture<Worker>> waitList = new ArrayList<>();
    workers.forEach(worker -> waitList.add(worker.stop()));

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 2000;
    for( CompletableFuture<Worker> cf : waitList ){
        long timeout = endTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
        if( timeout < 0 ){
            timeout = 0;
        }
        System.out.println("Get result waiting at most: " + timeout + " ms");
        try {
            Worker result = cf.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            System.out.println(result.name  + ": finished" );
        }
        catch( Exception e ){
            System.out.println("Failed to get result: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new TryWaitForCF().run();
}

static class Worker {
    private String name;
    private long timeToComplete;

    public Worker(String name){
        this.name = name;
        this.timeToComplete = (long) (Math.random() * (3000 - 1000 + 1) + 1000);
        System.out.println(name  + ": timeToComplete=" + timeToComplete);
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Worker> stop() {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(timeToComplete);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            return this;
        });
    }
}
```

}

results:

```
Worker=0: timeToComplete=1018
Worker=1: timeToComplete=1866
Worker=2: timeToComplete=1894
Worker=3: timeToComplete=2041
Worker=4: timeToComplete=1124
Worker=5: timeToComplete=1613
Worker=6: timeToComplete=2445
Worker=7: timeToComplete=2188
Worker=8: timeToComplete=2129
Worker=9: timeToComplete=2174
Get result waiting at most: 2000 ms
Worker=0: finished
Get result waiting at most: 980 ms
Worker=1: finished
Get result waiting at most: 130 ms
Worker=2: finished
Get result waiting at most: 100 ms
Failed to get result: null
Get result waiting at most: 0 ms
Worker=4: finished
Get result waiting at most: 0 ms
Worker=5: finished
Get result waiting at most: 0 ms
Failed to get result: null
Get result waiting at most: 0 ms
Failed to get result: null
Get result waiting at most: 0 ms
Failed to get result: null
Get result waiting at most: 0 ms
Failed to get result: null
```

You might want to change your design, though.